# Need to copy cell value to another cells in the html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using the simple html code where i want to copy the 1st cell value to all other cells.
[this how html table looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggHCM.jpg)
and also trying to autofill the remaining dates when i give the input in 1st cell

added my code below

Comment: Please include the code you have so far in your question, along with the specific problem you are having.

Comment: *"i want to copy the 1st cell value to all other cells"* - That's not what you want, because that would result in having the word "Date" in every cell in the table. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you want to do, when you want to do it (e.g., in response to some user action, or on page load), and show the relevant html and any JS you've tried.

Comment: There is no html code given....no javascript code attempt....and not even a specific programming question here. What are you expecting? Someone to write a whole module for you from scratch? Sorry...this isn't a code writing service. A good place to start would be [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want this, so i hope this is helpful

```js
function bindData(target) {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(target);

  if (inputs) {
    for (var k = 0; k < inputs.length; k++) {
      inputs[k].addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        var fields = document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.bind);
        var value = this.value;
        if (fields) {
          for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            fields[i].value = value;
          }
        }

      });
    }
  }

}

bindData('[data-bind]');
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-bind=".date" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="date" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="date" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-bind=".name" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="name" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="name" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Really shouldn't write code answers for questions that clearly don't meet basic site standards of a proper question.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the tip, I really want to help him, actually me also confused what he want, copy to whole cells or copy to same row cells. so i assumed he want this.  should i delete this answer?

Comment: up to you but I only suggest that a really poor question that shows no real effort to solve problem has no real long term value to this site. Question as it stands right now should be closed unless OP improves it considerably

Comment: Thanks @DININDU it really helped

Answer (score 0):

So you wanna change the values for the latter inputs according to the first input/select each line. Give them `id`s so we can add events with jQuery: `<input id="date-proto">` `<select id="name-proto">`. For the rest of each line, add a class each: `<input class="date-clone">` `<input class="name-clone">`. Now event listeners: `$('#date-proto').keyup(function() {$(.date-clone).val($(this).val());});` `$('#name-proto').change(function() {$(.name-clone).val($(this).val());});`. Usually I find `keyup` event on a text input better suits my needs, you can try `change` on it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the code i am working on...

<form><table>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker1").datepicker();
$("#datepicker2").datepicker();
$("#datepicker3").datepicker();
$("#datepicker4").datepicker();
$("#datepicker5").datepicker();
$("#datepicker6").datepicker();

  });
  </script>
<Th>Date</th>
<Td><input id="datepicker"/></td>
<Td><input id="datepicker1"/></td>
<Td><input id="datepicker2"/></td>
<Td><input id="datepicker3"/></td>
<Td><input id="datepicker4"/></td>
<Td><input id="datepicker5"/></td>
<Td> <input id="datepicker6"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Emp Name</th>
<td><input type="text" name="cell1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cell1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cell1"></td>

 </tr>
<th>Name:</Th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="source"></td>
<br><td>
</td> <td>
<input type="text" name="dest1"></td>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="copy" onclick="copy(this.form)">
<em>Check this box if you wanna copy.</em>
<P>

<br><br><td>
</td><td><input type="text" name="dest2"></td>
</td>
<br><td>
</td><td>
<input type="text" name="dest3"></td></td>
</form>
<script>function FillBilling(t) {
  if(t.copy.checked == true) {
   t.dest1.value = t.source.value;
    t.dest2.value = t.source.value;
  t.dest3.value = t.source.value;
  }
}</script>
```

Comment: i am getting the space issue and the function didn't work as expected